# Rational bijections $\mathbb R\to(0;1)$

Tags: real-analysis, real-algebraic-geometry

**Notation:**
$$ (0;1)\ :=\ \{x\in\mathbb R:\ 0<x<1\}$$

---

There are simple rational stretches $\ f \colon (0; \, 1)\to\mathbb R,\ $ e.g. let $\ s\in(0;\, 1);\ $ then
$$ f(x)\ :=\ \frac{1-s}{1-x}-\frac sx\ $$
is an increasing bijection $\ f \colon (0;\,1)\to\mathbb R\ $ such that $\ f(s)=0.$

In the other direction, there are rational surjections, such as $\ g \colon \mathbb R\to(0; \, 1]\ $ given by
$\ g(x)=\frac 1{1+x^2}.\ $

> **Question.** Does there exist a rational bijection $\ b \colon \mathbb R\to(0; \, 1)\ $?

=======================

EDIT: A stronger theorem holds:

**Theorem:**  Let $\ -\infty<a<b<\infty.\ $ Then there does not exist any surjective rational function $\ s:\mathbb R\to (a;b)$ onto the open interval $(a;b).$

**Proof:**  Function $s:\mathbb R\to(a;b),\ $ under the given assumptions, would admit a continuous extension defined in the projective line $ \mathbb P:=\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\},$
$$ q : \mathbb P\to[a;b] $$
Since $\mathbb P\ $ is compact, the image of it is a closed interval, actually

$$ q(\mathbb P) = [a;b] $$

However

$$ s(\mathbb R)\ \supseteq\ [a;b]\setminus \{q(\infty)\} $$

It follows that $\ a\in s(\mathbb R)\ $ or $\ b\in s(\mathbb R)\ $ -- a contradiction. **End of proof**

Comment: In mathematical English, a standard notation for the open interval is $(0, \, 1)$, not $(0; \; 1)$.

Comment: Another standard notation is $]0,1[$, especially when pairs $(0,1)$ come into play too..

Comment: @EmilJerabek, there was, till now, never any problem with my notation over several tens of years (way more than half a century). You're the first one who does not understand or are you pretending?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: The notation $(a; b)$ is fairly common in languages where a comma is the decimal separator, especially in handwritten mathematical texts. This way one clearly distinguishes between, say, $(1{,}1,2)$ and $(1,1{,}2)$. :-)

Comment: Notation $(a;b)$ has appeared on page 2, in the section *Notation* (*Oznaczenia*), of the University of Warsaw lecture notes "Introduction to Topology", the year 1968, by Włodzimierz Holsztyński. Students of mathematics, engineering, teachers, ... were using these lecture notes for many years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It should be monotone (as injective continuous function on the real line), but the limits on $\pm \infty$ are equal.

Comment: +1  Written more explicitly: if $f$ is a bounded rational function, then $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) .$$  Wlod should attempt to prove this.

Answer (score 8):

I think that the answer is negative.

You want a function having two horizontal asymptotes, namely the lines $y=0$ and $y=1$. But a rational function $$f(x)=\frac{a_nx^n+ a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0}{b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\ldots +b_0}$$ can have at most one horizontal asymptote: this happens either when $n=m$, in which case the asymptote is $y=a_n/b_m$, or when $n<m$, in which case the asymptote is $y=0$.

Allowing square roots, you can consider affine modifications of functions like $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}},$$ whose image is $(-1, \, 1)$.